# Adding complete ArgumentParser to a master parser?

Tags: python, argparse

The way to add subparsers using Python's argparse module is

```
import argparse
master_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('Master')
master_parser.add_argument('--master', help='arg for master parser')
subparsers = master_parser.add_subparsers(title='subcommands')

# add subparser
sub_parser = subparsers.add_parser('run')
sub_parser.add_argument('--sub', help='args for subparser')

master_parser.parse_args()
```

This works well and you can use

```
python test.py -h
python test.py run -h
```

to view the help message of both master and sub parser.

I am however in a situation in which I would like to add a complete program as a "plugin" to another program, so I would like to do something like

```
import argparse
master_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('Master')
master_parser.add_argument('--master', help='arg for master parser')
subparsers = master_parser.add_subparsers(title='subcommands')

# subparser defined in another module
sub_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('run')
sub_parser.add_argument('--sub', help='args for subparser')

# add subparser to the master parser. THIS DOES NOT WORK
subparsers.add_parser(sub_parser)

master_parser.parse_args()
```

Does anyone know a good way to achieve this? I suppose in the worst case I would need to dissect the sub_parser and feed it piece by piece to the master parser.

Comment: Explore the use of `parents`.

Comment: Thanks! The `parents` parameter is useful, basically the `subparsers.add_parser(sub_parser)` line should be replaced with ```subparsers.add_parser(prog=sub_parser.prog,
        description=sub_parser.description,
        epilog=sub_parser.epilog,
        help=sub_parser.description,
        parents=[sub_parser],
        add_help=False)```

Comment: This is interesting, you should answer you question with that code expanded and explained a little.